# How to add new selectlist to joomla 2.5 search plugin content

Tags: php, mysql, search, plugins, joomla2.5

Hi i am messing around offline with a joomla 2.5 website. I am currently trying to add a new slectlist to the joomla search component via the content search plugin.

I have duplicated the code for `"$ordering"` and changed the name to `"$license"`. I modified these files to include the new code:

```
plugin/search/content.php
com_search/views/search/content/view.html.php
com_search/models/search.php
com_search/controller.php
```

Everything loads fine but when it it comes to changing the search results with the new selectlist options it does not commit the MYSQL code for each option except the default option.

I figured out it has something to do with this line found in the search content plugin.

```
function onContentSearch($text, $phrase='', $ordering='', $areas=null, $license='')
```

If i add `$license=''` to the end it doesn't work. But if i get rid of the ordering variable in the above files, it works fine, but i want to keep both.

Anyone have any idea what i am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: @Richard Your feelings towards Joomla are irrelevant to the question at hand.

Comment: Understand, but don't use Joomla